# Neo4j OGM doesn't work in Play Framework HTTP GET after migration to version 3

Tags: playframework, neo4j-ogm

Today I migrated neo4j-ogm to the most recent version (3.0.1). I followed all recommendations but now when I try to query an entity I get a MappingException as the systems seems not able to find the Entity class. After further investigation and reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46453382/5102529) I tried to query in an HTTP POST response and it worked fine so it does seem to be a problem of using the neo4j-ogm Session to query inside a GET HTTP response as suggested in that other question answer. Any ideas on what might be going on here?

The Exception looks like:

```
play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$$anon$1: Execution exception[[MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of nodes.UserNode]]
        at play.api.http.HttpErrorHandlerExceptions$.throwableToUsefulException(HttpErrorHandler.scala:255)
        at play.api.http.DefaultHttpErrorHandler.onServerError(HttpErrorHandler.scala:180)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:251)
        at play.core.server.AkkaHttpServer$$anonfun$13$$anonfun$apply$1.applyOrElse(AkkaHttpServer.scala:250)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:346)
        at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recoverWith$1.apply(Future.scala:345)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
        at play.api.libs.streams.Execution$trampoline$.execute(Execution.scala:70)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
        at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.scala$concurrent$impl$Promise$DefaultPromise$$dispatchOrAddCallback(Promise.scala:280)
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Error mapping GraphModel to instance of nodes.UserNode
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:206)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:70)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:155)
        at controllers.UsersController.getUserMetrics(UsersController.java:372)
        at controllers.UsersController.index(UsersController.java:66)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Routes.scala:891)
        at router.Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$2$$anonfun$apply$2.apply(Routes.scala:891)
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.core.MappingException: Unable to load class with FQN: nodes.UserNode
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.reflect.EntityFactory.instantiateObjectFromTaxa(EntityFactory.java:109)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.reflect.EntityFactory.newObject(EntityFactory.java:58)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:217)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:203)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:135)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:89)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:70)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.delegates.LoadOneDelegate.load(LoadOneDelegate.java:46)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.session.Neo4jSession.load(Neo4jSession.java:155)
        at controllers.UsersController.getUserMetrics(UsersController.java:372)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: nodes.UserNode
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.reflect.EntityFactory.instantiateObjectFromTaxa(EntityFactory.java:106)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.reflect.EntityFactory.newObject(EntityFactory.java:58)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapNodes(GraphEntityMapper.java:217)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.mapEntities(GraphEntityMapper.java:203)
        at org.neo4j.ogm.context.GraphEntityMapper.map(GraphEntityMapper.java:135)
```

And the neo4j debug log looks like this:

```
[info] o.n.o.d.b.r.BoltRequest - Request: MATCH (n:`UserNode`) WHERE ID(n) = { id } WITH n RETURN n,[ [ (n)<-[r_p1:`PEER`]-(u1:`UserNode`) | [ r_p1, u1 ] ] ] with params {id=1}
[debug] o.n.o.d.b.d.BoltDriver - No current transaction, starting a new one
[debug] o.n.o.d.b.d.BoltDriver - Native transaction: org.neo4j.driver.internal.ExplicitTransaction@6acdd993
[debug] o.n.o.d.b.t.BoltTransaction - Committing native transaction: org.neo4j.driver.internal.ExplicitTransaction@6acdd993
[debug] o.n.o.t.Transaction - Thread 62: Commit transaction extent: 0
[debug] o.n.o.t.Transaction - Thread 62: Committed
[debug] o.n.o.t.Transaction - Thread 62: Close transaction extent: 0
[debug] o.n.o.t.Transaction - Thread 62: Closing transaction
[debug] o.n.o.m.MetaData - looking for concrete class to resolve label: UserNode
[debug] o.n.o.m.MetaData - concrete class found: org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassInfo@7abf416c. comparing with what's already been found previously...
[debug] o.n.o.m.MetaData - UserNode resolving class: org.neo4j.ogm.metadata.ClassInfo@7abf416c
[error] application -
```

I am using

- Play!Framework 2.6.6
- Java 1.8
- Scala 2.11.8
- Neo4j 3.3
- Neo4j-OGM 3.0.1

Comment: It's being investigated by the neo4j-ogm team here https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/429

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The suggested ClassLoader issue was effectivly the problem. However neo4j-ogm has a way to resolve it by itself. As suggested [here](https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-ogm/issues/429) it is possible for neo4j-ogm to nor rely on a class loader when loading the types. The code has been fixed and this should be ok on the next version of the ogm (current version with the problem is 3.0.1).

Answer (score 0):

The core problem seems to be a `ClassNotFoundException`. It looks like *neo4j-ogm* is trying to load the `nodes.UserNode` class, but can't find it.

It's possible that *neo4j-ogm* isn't using the correct `ClassLoader`. This is a common problem in Play because there are several `ClassLoader`s used in "dev mode" and the default one is often not correct.

To fix this, first get Play's correct `ClassLoader` by injecting a `play.Environment` (Play's Java API) or `play.api.Environment` (Play's Scala API). Then call the `classLoader` property on the `Environment` to get Play's `ClassLoader`.

Next, supply the `ClassLoader` to *neo4j-ogm* by either, passing it explicitly to *neo4j-ogm* (if the API supports it) or by using `Thread.setContextClassLoader()` to set the current thread's default `ClassLoader` (make sure you restore the old `ClassLoader` when you've finished).